# Access Element of a field Variable

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to access an element of a variable sent to the view

Here is my Controller

```
public function more($id)
{
    $chickdata = Gamefarm::where('id','=',$id)->get();
    $photos = Photo::where('chicken_id','=',$id)->get();
    return View::make('gamefarms/readmore',compact('chickdata','photos'));
}
```

I am sending the variable 'photo' to the views

Here is the code that i want to work on views

```
      @foreach ($photos as $myphotos) 
      @endforeach   
     <?php dd($myphotos->photo_loc[3]); ?>
```

Comment: im not familiar with Laravel, but I have used other MVC frameworks. You usually need to send an array to your view. Instead of `concat`, try an `array`

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
public function more($id){
    $chickdata = Gamefarm::where('id','=',$id)->get();
    $photos = Photo::where('chicken_id','=',$id)->get();
    $viewdata = array(
          'chickdata'=> $chickdata,
          'photos'=> $photos
    );
    return View::make('gamefarms/readmore', $viewdata);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view code is incorrect. It should be this.

```
@foreach ($photos as $myphotos) 
     {{ $myphotos->photo_loc[3] }}
@endforeach
```

No need to change your controller code - it is correct

Comment: @jake - did that answer your question?